# PHP Code not work in PHP CLI

Tags: php, mysql, command-line-interface

i made php code with database connection named test.php like below :

```
<?
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","monster");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* return name of current default database */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `earth` (`monster_id`, `type`, `name`) VALUES
(NULL, 'defender', 'tortoise')
")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

it works when i call via browser `http://localhost/learn/test.php` and data inserted to my database

but when i running in PHP CLI

```
php -r '    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","monster");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    /* return name of current default database */
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `earth` (`monster_id`, `type`, `name`) VALUES
    (NULL, 'defender', 'tortoise')
    ")) {
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
        $result->close();
    }
    $mysqli->close();'
```

no data inserted.
update **now i tes to eval($code); seems OKAY in windows but not in LINUX**

Comment: what error your getting ?

Comment: The syntax highlighter seems to think you have a quote escaping issue..

Comment: now i tes to eval($code); seems OKAY in windows but not in LINUX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
php -r '    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","monster");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    /* return name of current default database */
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `earth` (`monster_id`, `type`, `name`) VALUES
    (NULL, \'defender\', \'tortoise\')
    ")) {
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
        $result->close();
    }
    $mysqli->close();'
```

Comment: change 
(NULL, \'defender\', \'tortoise\')
to
(NULL, \"defender\", \"tortoise\")

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have kind of a syntax error there. You're starting your php code with ' and at the INSERT INTO statement you're wrapping your values also with '. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
php -r '    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","monster");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$type="defender";
$name="tortoise";
/* return name of current default database */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `earth` (`monster_id`, `type`, `name`) VALUES
(NULL, $type, $name)")) 
{
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}
$mysqli->close();'
```